Plotting of Lorenz and Bonferroni graphs
enter image description hereHow to draw the  Lorenz ( ()) and Bonferroni ( ()) curves for the given distribution with 3D version with interpretation with varying parameters, and when the CDF of the distribution does not have a closed form expression

f[[Eta], [Omega], [Delta]_] :=
ProbabilityDistribution[(

E^(-2 *x*\[Eta] - 

x^\[Delta]* \[Omega]) (4 *x^2 *\[Eta]^2 + 

x^\[Delta] *\[Delta] *\[Omega] + 

2 *x^(1 + \[Delta]) \[Eta] *\[Delta]* \[Omega]))/

x, {x, 0, \[Infinity]},

Assumptions -> \[Eta] > 0 && \[Omega] > 0 && \[Delta] > 0];

PDF[f[\[Eta], \[Omega], \[Delta]], x];


Write what integral you want to solve?

@MariuszIwaniuk have mentioned both of the functions which I want to plot

What is f(t) ?

There is a closed-form for the CDF:  cdf = Simplify[CDF[f[\[Eta], \[Omega], \[Delta]], x], x > 0] which results in $e^{-\omega  x^{\delta }-2 \eta  x} \left(e^{\omega  x^{\delta }+2 \eta  x}-2 \eta  x-1\right)$.  And if you set $\delta$ to specific integer values, you get a closed-form result.

Than you @JimB I have got the same form of the CDF but its quantile form is not in closed form  actually i have to mention that quantile function not CDF. Thank you for the help.

@MariuszIwaniukf(t) is given above just replace x by t
